Mathematical operation of scipy.signal.order_filter
I am intending to use the order_filter from scipy.signal in a project of mine. But I am not able to understand mathematically what it is doing.
The only direct resource I could find was its source code. Can someone explain it or direct me to some resources where I can study it?

Within each window (Sliding window over the image) it sorts the values in the local window.
The output is the $i$ -th value defined by rank.
For example, if the current window of size 3x3 is given by:
0.21222   0.336111  0.314628
0.361618  0.428665  0.737739
0.820733  0.218684  0.518375

Its sorted form:
0.21222019222091704
0.2186840749761242
0.3146279030640814
0.33611072119089247
0.36161795482075143
0.4286648700356096
0.518375126017995
0.7377387481628433
0.8207328180757468

If you chose rank = 3 the answer will be the 4th value (Python is zero based): 0.33611072119089247.
It is equivalent to MATLAB's ordfilt2().
Is it better documented, so you may get it by the examples there.
Internally it uses scipy.ndimage.rank_filter() which is better documented as well.

So, the function takes into account all the neighbouring elements of a pixel, with number of elements specified by the domain, sorts them, and replaces the pixel in question with the n th (n is rank) non-zero element of that list. Am I correct?

@Dhakshan, Yes, If you set 3x3 window it sorts the 9 values and returns 1 by the rank.
